# How to display results in a new page after running an ajax function from a node.js express server?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, ajax, express

So I'm creating a web app to be a stock management system, I'm using a node.js express server and mysql on the local host. I'm currently trying to when I click on one of the items in the list of stock that it will redirect me to a different html page which would display all the information of the item that is clicked on.

```
<script>
    function item_click(click) {

        var data = click.id;

        $.get("/getstockitem?id=" + data, function(data) {

            window.location.href = "stockInfoPage.html";
        });

</script>
```

This is the ajax function which sends the items id number through to the node server.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const http = require('http');
// viewed at http://localhost:8080

app.use(express.static('Website'));


app.listen(8080);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.get('/getstockitem', function (req, res) {

    var data = req.query;
    //var data = 1;

    console.log(data);



    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: 'password1',
        database: 'dissertation_database'
    });

    connection.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return req.next(err);
        }
        var sql = "SELECT * FROM stock where stock_id=" + data.id;
        connection.query(sql, function (err, result) {


            console.log(result);
            connection.end();
            res.json(result);
        });
    });

});
```

This is what my node.js server looks like at the moment. The console is logging the id number coming through and the query is pulling through the correct result the only issue is that when it redirects to the stockInfoPage.html it seems that the result is not passed through. I understand that more than likely when I call it in the next page as shown below that it will redo the query, I was wondering whats the best way to be able to get the next page to display the the data?

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'http://localhost:8080/getstockitem',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data) {
                        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                            console.log(data);


                            $("#itemName").append($('<p class="itemStaticText">Name: </p><p class="itemInfoText">' + data[i].stock_name + '</p>'));
                            $("#itemDescription").append($('<p class="itemStaticText">Description: </p><p class="itemInfoText">' + data[i].stock_description + '</p>'));
                            $("#itemQuantity").append($('<p class="itemStaticText">Quantity: </p><p class="itemInfoText">' + data[i].stock_quantity + '</p>'));
                            $("#itemShelf").append($('<p class="itemStaticText">Shelf Number: </p><p class="itemInfoText">' + data[i].shelf_number + '</p>'));
                            $("#itemRack").append($('<p class="itemStaticText">Rack Letter: </p><p class="itemInfoText">' + data[i].rack_letter + '</p>'));
                            $("#itemPrice").append($('<p class="itemStaticText">Price: </p><p class="itemInfoText">' + data[i].stock_price + '</p>'));

                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
```

***Edit***

So it is now working with a few minor changes thanks to the suggestion of terrymorse. Below I will put the changes just incase anyone else may have a similar issue.

```
<script>
    function item_click(click) {

        var data = click.id;

        window.location.href = "stockInfoPage.html?id=" + data;
    }

</script>
```

This time the Id number will be passed through in the url instead and then on the next page I added these lines to pull the id number from the url and now the query works as intended.

```
(document).ready(function() {

        var url = window.location.href;
        var id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('=') + 1);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/getstockitem?id=' + id,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
```

Comment: Can't you just pass the id as a query item (stockInfoPage.html?id=xx), then extract the id and get the data on the target page?

Comment: Okay so I gave that a try and it worked thank you, I passed it with the url instead of putting the id in the first get function. Then pulled it through from there and it works like a charm.

Comment: Well done, glad I could help.